# Compare pandas.Panel with series data for each item

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a pandas panel containing a dataframe filled with time series data for each panel item.  What I now want to do is compare each item with a set of reference data to determine if the item data exceeds the reference data at any time, in order to build a list of all items which exceed the reference data.  My intention was therefore to build a panel of boolean data and reduce it using `any()` to yield a 1D structure which masks the items.
As far as the comparison goes if I want to consider a single dataframe then the comparison succeeds fine, but if I try to compare the full panel with a  series, then I get back a dataframe not a panel.

```
>>>datapanel = pd.Panel(...)
>>>datapanel
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 10 (major_axis) x 3 (minor_axis)
Items axis: a to b
Major_axis axis: 0 to 9
Minor_axis axis: x to z

>>>refdata = pd.DataFrame(...)
>>>refdata
     x
3  0.1
4  0.2
>>>time_min = 3
>>>time_max = 4

# This comparison works as expected
>>>datapanel.ix['a',tmin:tmax,'x'] > refdata.ix[tmin:tmax,'x']
3    True
4    True

# This is what I want to do:
>>>datapanel.ix[:,tmin:tmax,'x'] > refdata.ix[tmin:tmax,'x']
       a      b      3      4
3  False  False  False  False
4  False  False  False  False
# but it gives a dataframe not a panel
```

How do I get what I want here?  I don't necessarily need a full panel of boolean data, but I certainly need a method to allow efficient application of a boolean expression to each item in the panel, and to construct a mask object for the items based upon it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My eventual solution was the [`Panel.select()`] method, which takes a function returning a boolean as its argument, and calls that function for each Panel item in turn, passing the index as an argument to the function.

```
datapanel.select(lambda id: (datapanel.ix[id,tmin:tmax,'x'] > refdata.ix[tmin:tmax,'x']).any())
```

or, since in the original question I asked for a list of all the items matching the specified criteria

```
datapanel.select(lambda id: (datapanel.ix[id,tmin:tmax,'x'] > refdata.ix[tmin:tmax,'x']).any()).items
```